# Is it "Aogiri Tree" or "Aogiri Wood"?

Tags: japanese-language, tokyo-ghoul

I've seen it translate to both in different sources when reading the manga. I think in the Anime it was "Aogiri Tree" but I can't quite remember.

Comment: In English localization the often used variant is Aogiri Tree or just Aogiri.

Comment: @AkiTanaka not quite, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23346/925

Comment: In the root A anime it was called Aogiri Tree. In the manga I think it was translated both ways.

Answer (score 2):

The name is Aogiri Tree, also referenced to several times as just Aogiri. The name of the organization is Aogiri Tree because the manga and anime translated it into English as Aogiri Tree.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Is this the official translation from the licensed manga/anime, or from fansub/scanlation?